# Como activar un Bootstrap floating label dinamicamente

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un input con Bootstrap floating label, y lo que me gustaría hacer es activar con javascript para obtener la animación como si hiciera un click sobre el input

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_1">
  <label for="form_control_1">Porcentaje</label>
  <span class="help-block" id="l1_aviso"></span></div>
```

Al hacer click sobre el input, se activa la animacion del floating-label, pero no logro activarlo desde dentro de una funcion con jquery
Por lo que investigué hasta ahora tiene un atributo "active" pero no logro activarlo

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué es lo que tienes y lo que necesitas. Te invito por favor a que revises [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: floating-label es un estilo de Bootstrap donde, al hacer foco en un input, el label recrea una animacion en la que sube hasta la parte superior del input. Se activa al hacer foco, pero yo quisiera que se active sin hacer click en el input, sino desde javascript

Comment: lo medio resolvi haciendo un focus con $("#form_control_1").focus(); aunque es una solucion alternativa